# Find out what columns in a table are NEVER used

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm not hoping for an answer with code, rather a strategy. I'm having to deal with a database which contains wast amounts of useless information, which is never even accessed. I'd even guesstimate the ratio of signal to noise being in favour of the noise. I'm looking for some statistic / analytic tool to help to find out what columns in what tables are never accessed.

Unfortunately, most of the time it would be columns (not tables) that aren't used. So I'd need to break it down to this level. I'm using SQL Server 2008, if that matters.

Comment: If it really is a wasteland, then you've probably got applications performing `SELECT *`s when they only want a few columns from the result set, and possibly even writing data that will never actually be used again (but because of the `SELECT *`s, will be included in result sets). That sort of combination makes any automated analysis impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an `audit`:

```
use master
GO

create server audit MyAudit
    to file (filepath = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA')
GO

alter server audit MyAudit
    with (state = on);
GO

use [<YourDatabase]
GO

create database audit specification MyDatabaseAudit
for server audit MyAudit
add (
    select on [<YouSchema>].[YourTable] by dbo
)
with (state = on)
GO

select [<YourColumn>] from [<YouSchema>].[YourTable]
GO

use master
GO

alter server audit MyAudit
    with (state = off);
GO

select * from sys.fn_get_audit_file ('C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MyAudit*',default,default);
GO
```

OK, so this won't allow you get as granular as a column, but because it captures each select statement, you should be able to get this information from the data it provides.

Obviously, the file path given above is just for the purposes of the example.

Another way would be a `SQL Profiler` trace, however, this also won't allow you to get to the level of a column, but just captures the select statements that are running. The downside of this is that you need to filter it correctly to just get the information you want, which can be bothersome. Also, can have higher overhead.

Comment: No prob. I know you asked for static analysis, but unless all your SQL is in views, functions and/or stored procs, the only analysis you can do using SQL Server is runtime. If all your SQL *is* in the database, let me know, and I can show you a static way.

Comment: Do you have regression tests?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to check this is to have access to all application code that’s accessing database and seeing how this code is used in the application. If you don’t have queries like select * from table then you’ll have an easy job.

**Examining application code:** nothing will give you a more precise overview than manual examination but that might take a long time. If your database access code is stored in one set of classes and classes are strongly coupled to database tables then you can just “Find all references” for each database column.

**Triggers:** setup insert,update,delete triggers on all suspect tables and then store all updated columns in a separate table. This will give you details on what columns are used most often for updates – therefore other columns will be the suspects for deleting.

**Profiling:** setup profiling for the suspect tables, run it for some time and analyze the logs.

**3rd party tools:** Use these tools to find all objects that are not referenced by any other object in database. Might be useful in identifying the suspect tables/columns. Try [SQL Dependancy tracker](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-dependency-tracker/)  or [ApexSQL Clean](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_clean.aspx)

Comment: No problem :)All requests should be captured by SQL Server Profiler. SQL Server doesn’t care if requests are made from PDO or SSMS or some other source. If you’re not seeing those requests in profiler trace, go ahead and check all filters in Profiler. There is probably something blocking those requests from being captured

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky and all data is getting accessed via SPs and there are no * then you can try using information_schema.columns table. something like `
select distinct '

```
select p.[type]
      ,p.[name]
      ,c.[definition]
  from sys.objects p
  join sys.sql_modules c
    on p.object_id = c.object_id
 where p.[type] = ''P''
   and c.[definition] like %'+COLUMN_NAME+'%' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

`

This query will need to be tweaked to execute produced SQL statements.